# Show that $x'(t)⋅ \nabla f(x)\geq0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define the gradient $\nabla f(x(t))$ as the vector with components $\partial f/\partial x_i$. If $x$ is a function of $t$ with derivative $x'(t)=v(t)$, how can I show that

$$ v \cdot \nabla f(x(t)) \geq 0 $$

when $t=0$
if $f(x(0))=0$

and if $f(x(t))\geq0$ when $t \gt 0$ ?

Comment: This is all a little muddled. Is the $x$ in $\nabla f(x)$ the function $x$ or a different variable?

Comment: Sorry, it's the function x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in general will only hold if $f$ is differentiable. When $f$ is differentiable, the chain rule gives

$$\frac{df}{dt} = x'(t)\cdot\nabla f(x(t))$$

if $f(t) \ge 0$ for $t > 0$ then consider $\frac{df}{dt}$ at $t=0$ given by

$$\frac{df}{dt}(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(h)}{h} \ge 0$$

where the second last step is due to the differentiability of $f$ at $0$ and the last step is due to the fact that $f(h) \ge 0$ when $h > 0$.